# Multiple instance of application but run only one

Tags: c#, mutex

I have a unmanaged application which opens at runtime my managed application.
- Each time the unmanaged aplication is being executed , it opens a new instance of my application .

I have to somehow do this scenario:

-When the unmanaged application is being executed for the first time, my managed aplication should run fine,but if the user tries to open again the unmanaged application , those managed instances should be in "standby" mode and if the first managed application which is currently running is closed , one of the standby instances should be "resumed" .

As I've seen so far , I should be using mutex :

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!IsSingleInstance())
        {

            this.Close();
            return;
        }
    }
    private static Mutex _mutex;
    private static bool IsSingleInstance()
    {
        _mutex = new Mutex(false, "MyApp");

        GC.KeepAlive(_mutex);

        try
        {
            return _mutex.WaitOne(0, false);
        }
        catch (AbandonedMutexException)
        {

            _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            return _mutex.WaitOne(0, false);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mutex != null)
        {
            _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
```

But ofcourse , the code only checks if another istance is running and if it does..then it will close it.

What can I do?

Thanks,

Comment: "Stand-by mode" doesn't mean anything in Windows, it doesn't provide a way to "freeze" a process.  It should be programmed into the code itself.  You could hack something like pinvoking SuspendThread on all the threads owned by the process but that is pretty troublesome.  Best to re-think what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather put the lock in Main in Program.cs.

```
static void Main()
{
    Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "MyApp");
    if (mutex.WaitOne())
    {
        try
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
}
```